# How do I get the name and version of the list item workflow from SharePoint 2013 using PowerShell script

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell-script

[image]

How can I get the name and version of the list item workflow as encircled in the image?

I have written the below code to obtain the Workflow ID, Title ,Status, Item Name. I got the ID, STatus and ItemName ,But not able to get the Workflow name and workflow version. Can anyone please help me with this?

#

foreach ($item in $list.Items)
    {
        foreach($workflow in $item.workflows)
        {
            $wfID = $workflow.InstanceID
            $wfName = $wf.Name
            $wfStatus = $workflow.InternalState
            $wfListItem = $workflow.ItemName

```
        write-host "Workflow ID :$wfID Title: $wfName Status: $wfStatus ListItem: $wfListItem"
    }
}
```

#